# Email bounces back with Status 4.4.7

Tags: php

I send automatic order-confirmation mails to customers using PHPMailer.

<99% reach the intended mail account with hotmail, gmail, yahoo etc. etc.

BUT - there are a few minor servers (comhem.se / bredband.net) that ALWAYS returns the mails after 2-3 days with Status 4.4.7

Example:
*Final-Recipient: rfc822;aaa.bbb@comhem.se
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.7*

If I resend the message from the same sending adress but through a gmail-account it goes through to customer. From my understanding there must be something on receiving server wrongly configured and I have been in contact with administrators that sadly enough seems to lack knowledge to resolve the issue - or simply just ignore the matter.

There are NEVER more than 1 recipient to the emails. There are NEVER any attachment to the emails and they are not big.

I have had extensive discussion with my own hosting service company and they tell me the issue MUST be on receiving side.

Does anybody have a clue how or what to tell the receiving admin to do? or possibly how to adjust my sending details somehow

Comment: Maybe a example of sent email could help us help you :)

Comment: Could it be that your server sends mails that are categorized as spam by the receiving server?

Comment: The content of the mail does not matter - it is certein receiving (smaller) servers that do not accept - This is one example: Hej Miss Xxxxxx!

Du har bett oss meddela dig när nedanstående produkt/er finns att beställa.

Lilium species - 1st el. frp Night Rider - finns nu att beställa

Den nya höstkatalogen har nyligen öppnat!
Beställ via vår webshop här : Bulbs.se

Välkommen med din beställning
Blommande hälsningar
Anita & Bosse - only text UTF8

Comment: It could be some faulty spam blocking - but how could I possibly find out? There are no blacklist issues